# Php passing object by value

Tags: php, recursion, reference

I am playing a bit with recursion in php. Unfortunately php value smart copying idea and passing objects by reference by default is not making it easier. Problem occur because modifications made by iteration number X are visible in iteration ex X-2

For example:

```
/**
 * Silly function to find last element in array
 * @param ArrayObject $input  
 */
function process(ArrayObject $input) {
    if ($input->count() == 1) {
        return $input->getIterator()->current();
    }
    $ar = $input->getArrayCopy();
    array_shift($ar);
    $input->exchangeArray($ar);
    return process($input);
}

$in = new ArrayObject(range('a', 'd'));
echo 'Before ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($in);
echo PHP_EOL . 'Process - last element is: ' . process($in) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'After ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($in);
```

output is

```
Before 
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
}

Process - last element is: d
After 
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
}
```

as you see recursion modified also original $in variable, what I expect is that every new iteration will operate on copy of value. In this example it is not needed, but what in case that recursion function is more complicated.

Simple solution - clone

```
function process(ArrayObject $input) {
    $input = clone ($input);
    if ($input->count() == 1) {
        return $input->getIterator()->current();
    }
    $ar = $input->getArrayCopy();
    array_shift($ar);
    $input->exchangeArray($ar);
    return process($input);
}
```

ok, works but what if input is very complicated multi-object nested  recurred structure?
Ok then I can serialize and unserialze value as a substitute for deep copy

```
function process(ArrayObject $input) {
    $input = unserialize(serialize($input));
    if ($input->count() == 1) {
        return $input->getIterator()->current();
    }
    $ar = $input->getArrayCopy();
    array_shift($ar);
    $input->exchangeArray($ar);
    return process($input);
}
```

perfect - it works, but it is a bit waste of time and cpu to  un/serialize in every iteration (especially with huge $input).

Is there any other way to do it, something what lets me not worry that I need to 'hack a bit' to use php for standard usage.

//EDIT example with Tigrang suggestion

Tigrang your suggestion was very interesting, but

```
function process(ArrayObject $input) {
    $input = new ArrayObject(($input));
    $input->offsetSet(null, 'f');
}

$in = new ArrayObject(range('a', 'd'));
echo 'Before ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($in);
process($in);
echo 'After ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($in);

 After 
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
}
```

it still keeps reference to external variable

//edit 2

```
class Engine {

    public $power = 999;

}

class Car {

    public $name = '';
    public $engine = '';

    public function __construct($name, $power) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->engine = new Engine();
        $this->engine->power = $power;
    }

}

function process(ArrayObject $input) {
    $input = new ArrayObject(($input->getArrayCopy()));
    $ford = $input[0];
    $ford->name = 'Audi';
    $ford->engine->power  = 1500;
}

$ar = array(new Car('Ford',  130));
$in = new ArrayObject($ar);
echo 'Before ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($in);
process($in);
echo 'After ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($in);
```

Comment: Have you considered using arrays instead of objects?

Comment: How about using `clone`?

Comment: @Truth - yes but I would like to use objects

Comment: @zerkms - please read description under third grey box, copy is not a perfect solution (unfortunately)

Comment: @mrok: Why? There's no advantage whatsoever in iterating objects instead of arrays. In fact, the opposite is true, arrays have better performance, and are easier to traverse and manipulate using array functions.

Comment: "copy is not a perfect solution" - you don't want explicit clone operation, but looking for magic implicit one. Sounds inconsistent.

Comment: "but it is a bit waste of time and cpu to un/serialize in every iteration" --- and that's what you want asking how to pass object by value. By value means that everything will be copied each time

Comment: @Truth - is it not a production code, I am just practicing and I would like to solve it without arrays.

Comment: @zerkms - I am looking for solution similar one to passing scalar variable to function (they are just copied). Who knows maybe php internally call serialize and unserialize in this operation ;)

Comment: @mrok: but you've just said you don't like serializing because it consumes CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this is a limitation in PHP. And as you pointed out this happens because of two things in PHP 5x which are not complimentary.

- Objects are always passed as references
- clone() only does shallow copy and there is no deep copy mechanism inherent in the language

`unserialize(serialize($obj)` is the only (highly inefficient) work-around currently available. Lets hope the Gods-that-be sort out some of these issues in the upcoming versions, instead of only breaking their head about how to implement unicode in the much-hyped (and delayed) version 6!

Answer (score 0):

Why not `$input = new ArrayObject($input);`

As far as I can tell it copies deeply nested and is faster than serialize: http://viper-7.com/kHLCCP

Comment: Interesting, but still does not solve the problem, please look at question update.

Comment: Then try `$input = new ArrayObject($input->getArrayCopy());` Still faster than serialize

Comment: a bit better - but still does not work with objects, please check 2nd update

Comment: Ah I see the issue with it now. I guess serializing *is* the only option.